# Sorting a list based on user input on a webpage

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to write a webpage that presents the user with two options from a list and asks them which is better. I repeat this until the list is sorted. I am having trouble understanding how I can do this in javascript. I've tried a few things, but none of them have worked yet.

If this was in, say, C++, I would just write a class and then overload the < operator to ask for user input via cin or whatever, but that doesn't really work in a webpage. I'm attempting something similar with:

```
class Character {
    constructor(initName, initPicture, initColor) {
            this.name = initName;
            this.picture = initPicture;
            this.color = initColor;
    }
    async set1() {
            console.log("should display " + this.name);
            document.getElementById("pic1").src = this.picture;
            document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = this.name;
            document.getElementById("character1").style.background = this.color;
            console.log("displayed " + this.name);
    }
    async set2() {
            console.log("should display " + this.name);
            document.getElementById("pic2").src = this.picture;
            document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = this.name;
            document.getElementById("character2").style.background = this.color;
            console.log("displayed " + this.name);
    }
}
var decision = false;
async function compare(a, b) {
    console.log("comparing " + a.name + " to " + b.name);
    a.set1();
    b.set2();
    console.log("after display");
    const nameA = a.name;
    const nameB = b.name;
    /*while (!decision) {
    }*/
//      var result = prompt("Who is better, " + a.name + " or " + b.name
 + "?");
    let comparison = 0;
    if (result === nameA) {
            comparison = 1;
    }
    else if (result === nameB) {
            comparison = 0;
    }
    console.log(comparison);
    return comparison;
}
```

Essentially, the two commented lines were two ways of trying to see what would happen if the function was stalled. When this happens, nothing is rendered to the screen via set1 or set2  (which I know are called because of the console.log).

Eventually, I plan to store the result of the comparison in a database and check to see if the comparison has already been made first. The user will choose through clicking on one of the divs (not implemented yet).

I'm not really looking to 'debug' my code per-se since it technically works; I'm just not sure how to approach this problem. I don't think that the way I am doing it now is the best.

By the way, I'm not using the library sort function since it doesn't like async functions.

What kind of algorithm/srtucture would you use to write a webpage that sorts a list based on the user choosing which is greater?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do in javascript is somehow async (except `promt`), so you just have to make it possible to *await* the user clicking one of the divs. For that we just build a Promise that resolves when the click event occurs on a certain element:

```
function wasClicked(el) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", function handler() {
        el.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        resolve(el);
    });
  });
}
```

Then you can change your comparison to:

```
static async function compare(a, b) { // <- should be static
  console.log("comparing " + a.name + " to " + b.name);
  a.set1();
  b.set2();
  console.log("after display");

  const pic1 = document.getElementById("pic1");
  const pic2 = document.getElementById("pic2");

  const choice = await Promise.race(wasClicked(pick), wasClicked(pic2));
 return choice === pic1 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Now we only need a way to sort an array asynchronoulsy, but thats quite easy:

```
 async function asyncSort(array, comparator) {
   for(let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
     if(await comparator(array[i], array[i + 1]) < 0) {
        ([array[i], array[i + 1]] = [[array[i + 1], array[i]]);
        i -= 2;
     }
   }
}
```

So you can now do:

```
asyncSort(someArray, Character.compare);
```

*PS: classes should by convention just contain methods that are "traits" of the class, e.g. `Character.speak()`, neither `set1` nor `set2` do that so they should not be methods of Character*

Comment: Thanks!  After some reading about how Promises worked, I was able to get this up and working! As for the class thing, is that a javascript convention? Because that's not how I usually see classes used, but I rarely see classes used at all in javascript...

Comment: @avery thats rather a general OOP convention